# What is the Python equivalent of Perl's ucfirst() or s///e?

Tags: python, string

I need to capitalize a string in Python, without also converting the rest of the string to lower-case. This seems trivial but I can't seem to find a simple way to do it in Python.

Given a string like this:

```
"i'm Brian, and so's my wife!"
```

In Perl I could do this:

```
ucfirst($string)
```

which would produce the result I need:

```
I'm Brian, and so's my wife!
```

Or with Perl's regular expression modifiers I could also do something like this:

```
$string =~ s/^([a-z])/uc $1/e;
```

and that would work ok too:

```
> perl -l
$s = "i'm Brian, and so's my wife!";
$s =~ s/^([a-z])/uc $1/e;
print $s;
[Control d to exit]
I'm Brian, and so's my wife!
>
```

But in Python, the str.capitalize() method lower-cases the whole string first:

```
>>> s = "i'm Brian, and so's my wife!"
>>> s.capitalize()
"I'm brian, and so's my wife!"
>>>
```

While the title() method upper-cases every word, not just the first one:

```
>>> s.title()
"I'M Brian, And So'S My Wife!" 
>>>
```

Is there any simple/one-line way in Python of capitalizing only the first letter of a string without lower-casing the rest of the string?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about:

```
s = "i'm Brian, and so's my wife!"
print s[0].upper() + s[1:]
```

The output is:

```
I'm Brian, and so's my wife!
```

Comment: In Perl, `ucfirst`-ing an undefined value isn't fatal, so to use rely on this you should `try` and `catch` it, but that's normal anyway. :-)

Comment: It isn't a pythonic way :(

Answer (score 29):

If what you are interested in is upcasing *every* first character and lower casing the rest (not exactly what the OP is asking for), this is much cleaner:

```
string.title()
```

Comment: so good, the best, especially when there are lot of unnecessary uppercase letters in the string

Comment: -1 Perl's `ucfirst` works very differently from `title`: `ucfirst` acts solely on the first letter of the string, whereas Python's `title` capitalizes all words and transforms the others letters to lower case. So `"i'm Brian, and so's my wife!".title()` would result in `"I'M Brian, And So'S My Wife!"` which is quite different from the result of ucfirst in Perl: `"I'm Brian, and so's my wife!"`

Comment: how come this is more voted than the actual solution? This is VERY different from `ucfirst()` from Perl/PHP, the OP even explicitly mention in the the question! :facepalm:

Answer (score 9):

Just use string slicing:

```
s[:1].upper() + s[1:]
```

Then, it works even if `s` is empty.

Note that strings are immutable; this, just like `capitalize()`, returns a new string.